# Google App Engine - Add search fields for multiple tags (adding multiple tags to search)?

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-search

I want use Search API but not know how to add multiple tags - it is not describe clearly.

Can I do such thing:

```
fields = []
for tag in self.tags:
  fields.append(search.TextField(name = 'tag', value = tag))
```

Or it need different approach since multiple 'tag' fields is not possible?

Answer (score 3):

It is not true that "multiple tag fields is not possible". You can have multiple fields with the same name.

Comment: We definitely support this. See "multi-valued fields" here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/#document_fields

Answer (score 1):

You can whitespace concatenate all the tags into one text field.

If you're only interested in matching documents and don't require the tags to be structured as separate field, a query matching any tag will return the document as a match. This also helps when searching on multiple tags, because the document can have a higher relevance if it has both.